Intuition behind Equivalence classes of Double Cosets
Let G be a group. Let A, B be subgroups of G. If x, y ∈ G, define the relation ∼ as follows: x ∼ y if y = axb, for some a ∈ A, b ∈ B. I understand why ~ is defines an equivalence relation on G and the equivalence class of x is [x] = AxB = {a x b | a ∈ A, b ∈ B}. However, I want to get some intuition behind what those partitions really are and how they are dependent on A and B.
I understand that one class will be AB (when x = e, e is the identity of G). but I don't understand what other classes will be and how they relate with the relationship between A and B, for example if A is a subset B or when A and B are disjoint?

Here's a MathJax tutorial :)

If we let $\Omega$ be the set of right cosets of the subgroup $A$ of $G$, then there is a natural right action of $G$ on $\Omega$ by multiplication on the right. (There is a standard result that any transitive right action of $G$ is equivalent to a coset action of this type.)
Now the orbits of the subgroup $B$ in this action correspond to the double cosets $AxB$.
(If you prefer left actions, just take the orbits of $A$ on the left cosets of $B$.)

Here are some perspectives on "what" double cosets are.
One is that they are the orbits of a certain action. Specifically, the direct product $A \times B$ acts on $G$ by $(a,b) \cdot g = agb^{-1}$ for all $(a,b) \in A \times B$ and $g \in G$. The orbits of this action are the $(A,B)$-double cosets in $G$.
Another observation is the following.
$AxB = \cup_{a \in A} axB$, so $AxB$ is always an union of some number of left cosets of $B$ in $G$.
$AxB = \cup_{b \in B} Axb$, so $AxB$ is always an union of some number of right cosets of $A$ in $G$.
Specifically $AxB $ can be written as a disjoint union $$AxB = y_1B \cup \cdots \cup y_tB = Az_1 \cup \cdots \cup Az_s$$ in two different ways.
In the case where $A$ and $B$ are finite, you have the following formula for the size of a double coset:
$$|AxB| = \frac{|A|\cdot|B|}{|A \cap xBx^{-1}|} = \frac{|A|\cdot|B|}{|x^{-1}Ax \cap B|}$$
So $AxB$ is the union of $t = [A : A \cap xBx^{-1}]$ left cosets of $B$, and $s = [B : x^{-1}Ax \cap B]$ right cosets of $A$.

@MartinBrandenburg: Thanks, that's right.

Remark: We adopt the left-action convention.
It is familiar to us that every transitive action of group $G$ can be regarded as a left regular action about a subgroup $K \le G$ up to $G$-set isomorphism, as follows:
$ G \times G/K \rightarrow G/K, \ (g,xK) \mapsto gxK$
If the above action is important, then so is its subgroup action! And we will see that the Double coset is just a natural concept in the process of studying this action.
Now, let $G$ be a group, $H$ and $K$ subgroups of $G$. We can construct the following action naturally:
$\varphi: H \times G/K \rightarrow G/K, \ (h,xK) \mapsto hxK$

Orbit: $H \cdot (xK) = HxK/\sim_{G/K}$ $(g_1 \sim_{G/K} g_2 \Leftrightarrow g_1K = g_2K)$. So there is an one-to-one correspondence between $(H,K)$-double cosets in $G$ and orbits of $\varphi$.
Stabilizer: $Stab(xK) = \left\{h \in H \mid hxK=xK\right\} = \left\{h \in H \mid h \in xKx^{-1} \right\} = H \cap xKx^{-1}$
kernel: $Ker(\varphi) = \cap_{x \in G}Stab(xK) = H \cap (\cap_{x \in G}xKx^{-1})$, in which $\cap_{x \in G}xKx^{-1}$ is the normal core of $K$ , i.e. the maximal normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $K$.

For any $x \in G$, we can induce an $H$-set isomorphism by above facts and the property of transitive group action:
$H/H \cap xKx^{-1} \rightarrow H \cdot (xK) = HxK/\sim_{G/K}$
And then $\left| HxK/\sim_{G/K} \right| = \left| H/H \cap xKx^{-1} \right|$. If $HxK$ is finite, we can also derive that  $\left| HxK \right| = \left| K \right| \cdot \left| H/H \cap xKx^{-1} \right|$. This tell us that the sizes of $(H,K)$-double coset and stabilizer of $\varphi$ are determined by each other.

To begin with, double-coset spaces $A\backslash G/B$ are much subtler than "single-" coset spaces $G/B$. The latter has $G$ acting on the left, and the fibering $G\to G/B$ is very homogeneous. In contrast, there's no reliable group action on $A\backslash G/B$, and the fibers of the quotient map can have wildly varying cardinalities.
Topologically (or smooth-manifold-wise), spaces $G/B$ are nice, while $A\backslash G/B$ can be crazy.
A Bruhat decomposition $G=\bigcup_w PwP$ of a reductive group, where $P$ is a parabolic subgroup, and $w$ runs over (representatives of) the Weyl group, is a relatively happy example: topologically, the boundary relations of the various "cells" $PwP$ are nicely explicated in terms of the Weyl group.
In trying to discover integral representations of automorphic $L$-functions, looking at $H\backslash G/P$ for more general subgroups $H$ is relevant... and is quite complicated in general.
